# Left outer join not working on postgres

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a sales table, products table, and categories table that I'm trying to join. I want all the rows from the products table that match with the rows from the categories table. Then i want to join the sales table but I only want the rows from the sales table that match with the products table. This is what my sql looks like:

```
create table productsandcat as 
select p.p_id, p.p_name, p.p_price, c.c_name, s.s_price, s.quantity 
from products p
join categories c on p.cid = c.c_id
left outer join sales s on s.pid = p.p_id
```

but it's not working as intended. This returns me all the rows from the sales table but I only want the rows that match with the products and categories table.

For example:

```
Products table:

p_id    p_name   p_price   cid
1        a          1       0
2        b          1        1
3        c           1       2

Categories table:
c_id   c_name
0         a1
1          a2
2          a3

sales table:
pid   quantity
1       1
4        1
5         2

productsandcat table:
p_id   p_name   p_price   c_name   s_price   quantity
1        a        1         a1        1      1
2        b        1         a2       0       0
3        c         1        a3       0       0
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are using a create table rather than just a select?

Comment: yes, this table will have more computations performed on it so I need to make it a table

Comment: And a view won't do?  Duplicating data across tables is usually not a good idea.

Comment: For the sake of runtime, I am going to stick with tables. I know its not a good idea but I will update this new table if the other tables change

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an AND on your left outer join that has the condition to the categories table.

```
select p.p_id, p.p_name, p.p_price, c.c_name, s.s_price, s.quantity 
from products p
join categories c on p.cid = c.c_id
left outer join sales s on s.pid = p.p_id and s.cid = c.c_id
```

Or don't use a left outer join if you don't have the category on the sales

```
select p.p_id, p.p_name, p.p_price, c.c_name, s.s_price, s.quantity 
from products p
join categories c on p.cid = c.c_id
join sales s on s.pid = p.p_id
```

Comment: if i dont use a left outer join, it won't give me what I want. Im basically trying to join the categories table with products table. And then take that table that i just joined and do a left outer join with the sales table. Is that possible?

Comment: Please add the structure of the tables to the question with some sample rows and also sample output to demonstrate what you are after, as it stands it is a bit unclear.

Comment: just added a sample in the question